# The flash notice message is not displaying " ruby on rails"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, flash-message

I searched for an answer before I came here but found nothing.
I have this in my controller

```
def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    if @article.save
        flash[:notice] = "Article was successfully created"
        redirect_to article_path(@article)
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

and I add this in my application.html.erb:

```
<body>
  <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <ul>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
<%= yield %>
```

and here is my show.html.erb:

```
<h1>Showing selected article</h1>

<p>
  Title: <%= @article.title %>
</p>

<p>
  Description: <%= @article.description %>
</p>
```

After submitting the form I go to the show page,the flash notice does not display. why?

Comment: could I get link to your github repo? I am working on the same chapter. Also please add your session_controller.rb and account_activation_controller.rb files

Comment: Here is my github repo -- https://github.com/sam0191/alpha-blog --

Comment: is this about Michael Hartl's Tutorial? Chapter 10?

Comment: No it is from guy name Mashrur Hossain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have look into your github repo, it seems that you are not using application.html.erb as your layout, because your article controller is inherited from `ActionController::Base`

There are 2 ways you can do this.

You can either change your controller file to inherit from ApplicationController:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

end
```

Or you can add default layout to the controller file:

```
class ArticlesController < ActionController::Base
layout 'application'

end
```

Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Great,  that was my problem that the articles controller have to be inherit from application controller...Thank you a lot for that

Comment: I still cant upvote because I dont have 15 points yet..but how to mark this question as the correct one?? I dont know??... Also I provide the link of your answer to the course community that I participate with